# Can't make my script fetch desired content using proxies

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium using ***proxies*** to get the text of differnt links populated upon navigating to a url, as in ***[this one](http://www.google.com/search?q=python)***. What I want to parse from there is the visible text connected to each link.

The script I've tried so far with is capable of producing new proxies when this function `start_script()` is called within it. The problem is that the very url lead me to this [redirected link](http://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dpython&q=EgRDzZHQGMrKpOEFIhkA8aeDS9qoBxMmhdCvE4igbYlPhCxZiFNjMgFy). I can get rid off this redirection only when I keep trying on until the url is satisfied with a proxy. My current script can try twice only with two new proxies.

***How can I use any loop within `get_texts()` function in such a way so that it will keep trying using new proxies until it parses the required content?***

My attempt so far:

```
import requests
import random
from itertools import cycle
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=python'

def get_proxies():   
    response = requests.get('https://www.us-proxy.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    proxies = [':'.join([item.select_one("td").text,item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text]) for item in soup.select("table.table tbody tr") if "yes" in item.text]
    return proxies

def start_script():
    proxies = get_proxies()
    random.shuffle(proxies)
    proxy = next(cycle(proxies))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def get_texts(url):
    driver = start_script()
    driver.get(url)
    if "index?continue" not in driver.current_url:
        for item in [items.text for items in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")]:
            print(item)
    else:
        get_texts(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_texts(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works well for me, however it can't help you with bad proxies. It also loops through the list of proxies and tries one until it succeeds or the list runs out.
It prints which proxy it uses so that you can see that it tries more than one time.

However as https://www.us-proxy.org/ points out:

> What is Google proxy? Proxies that support searching on Google are
>   called Google proxy. Some programs need them to make large number of
>   queries on Google. Since year 2016, all the Google proxies are dead.
>   Read that article for more information.

[Article:](https://www.my-proxy.com/blog/google-proxies-dead)

> Google Blocks Proxy in 2016 Google shows a page to verify that you are
>   a human instead of the robot if a proxy is detected. Before the year
>   2016, Google allows using that proxy for some time if you can pass
>   this human verification.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import random

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver


def get_proxies():   
    response = requests.get('https://www.us-proxy.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    proxies = [':'.join([item.select_one("td").text,item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text]) for item in soup.select("table.table tbody tr") if "yes" in item.text]
    random.shuffle(proxies)
    return proxies


# Only need to fetch the proxies once
PROXIES = get_proxies()


@contextmanager
def proxy_driver():
    try:
        proxy = PROXIES.pop()
        print(f'Running with proxy {proxy}')
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        yield driver
    finally:
        driver.close()

def get_texts(url):
    with proxy_driver() as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        if "index?continue" not in driver.current_url:
            return [items.text for items in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")]
        print('recaptcha')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=python'
    while True:
        links = get_texts(link)
        if links:
            break
    print(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
  driver = start_script()
  driver.get(url)
  if "index?continue" in driver.current_url:
    continue
  else:
    break
```

This will loop until `index?continue` is not in the url, and then `break` out of the loop.

This answer only addresses your specific question - it doesn't address the problem that you might be creating a large number of web drivers, but you never destroy the unsused / failed ones. Hint: you should.

Comment: Actually you can do just `if not "index?continue" in driver.current_url: break` - no need to use `else` block

Comment: Although, It's within a while loop, I highly doubt your suggested change will make the script run more than once @Danielle M.

Comment: @asmitu What makes you doubt it?

Comment: An execution @Danielle M. I have already tried and that was the feedback.